# Which join to use

Tags: mysql, php

So I have a database I'm trying to convert to a new one, it has around 40k rows in let's call it table A, now the actual data is in table B which has over 1.6 mil rows.

When I'm writing my PHP script I'm calling the DB every time to connect table B instead of using a join and due to the mass amount of queries its stopping on row 3205 or something, but when I don't connect table B it goes all the way to end.

What I want to do it have a neat way of connecting table A to table B in one query but I suck with joins.

Here's what the problem looks like:

#### Table A

```
ID
Something
Something 2
etc...
```

#### Table B

```
ID
TableA ID 
Something
```

Of the top of my head I'm thinking I'd join table A onto table B and table B has the majority of records but again as I said I'm no good at joins.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Table B` 
RIGHT JOIN  `Table A` 
ON  `Table B`.`Table A ID`=`Table A`.`Table A ID`
```

Runs a little slow. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, First of all, welcome to the site. We need a little more information to work with here. Can you post the table structure and explain plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheat sheet:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  B
    JOIN  A  ON B.x = A.x
```

finds rows that are in both tables.  `INNER JOIN` is a synonym.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  B
    LEFT JOIN  A  ON B.x = A.x
    WHERE A.x IS NULL;
```

finds rows that are in B but not A.

`RIGHT` is `LEFT` with the table names swapped everywhere.  (Nobody uses `RIGHT`.)

`CROSS JOIN` a regular `JOIN`, but without an `ON`.  You get all combinations of rows in the two tables.  (Unless the `WHERE` tosses some.)

Be sure to always use qualify all columns with the table it comes from.  If the table names are long; use aliases  (`FROM long_table_name AS ltn`)

Index the column (or combination of columns) in the ON.  Often it is the `PRIMARY KEY` in one of the tables.  A `PRIMARY KEY` is an index; don't add another index.